# Google search from python app

Tags: python, google-search-api

I'm trying to take an input file read each line and search google with that line and print the search results from the query. I get the first search result which is from wikipedia which is great but then I get the error: File "test.py", line 24, in 
    dictionary[str(lineToRead)].append(str(i))
KeyError: 'mouse'

```
input file pets.txt looks like this:
cat 
dog
bird
mouse

inputFile = open("pets.txt", 'r') # Makes File object
outputFile = open("results.csv", "w") 
dictionary = {}  # Our "hash table"
compare = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" # urls will compare against this string


for line in inputFile.read().splitlines():
    # ---- testing ---
    print line 
    lineToRead = line
inputFile.close()

from googlesearch import GoogleSearch
gs = GoogleSearch(lineToRead)
#gs.results_per_page = 5
#results = gs.get_results()  

for i in gs.top_urls():
    print i # check to make sure this is printing out url's
    compare2 = i
    if compare in compare2: # compare the two url's
        dictionary[str(lineToRead)].append(str(i)) #write out query string to dictionary key & append the urls


for i in dictionary:
    print i
    outputFile.write(str(i))
    for j in dictionary[i]: 
        print j
        outputFile.write(str(j))
        #outputFile.write(str(i)) #write results for the query string to the results file.

#to check if hash works print key /n print values /n print : /n print /n

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You're calling to dictionary[str(lineToRead)].append without ever defining dictionary[str(lineToRead)].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeremy Banks is right.  If you write `dictionary[str(lineToRead)].append(str(i))` without first initializing a value for `dictionary[str(lineToRead)]` you will get an error.

It looks like you have an additional bug.  The value of `lineToRead` will always be `mouse`, since you have already looped through and closed your input file before searching for anything.  Likely, you want to loop thru every word in inputFile (i.e. cat, dog, bird, mouse)

To fix this, we can write the following (assuming you want to keep a list of query strings as values in the dictionary for each search term):

```
for line in inputFile.read().splitlines(): # loop through each line in input file
  lineToRead = line
  dictionary[str(lineToRead)] = [] #initialize to empty list
  for i in gs.top_urls():
     print i # check to make sure this is printing out url's
     compare2 = i
     if compare in compare2: # compare the two url's
       dictionary[str(lineToRead)].append(str(i)) #write out query string to dictionary key & append the urls
inputfile.close()
```

You can delete the for loop you wrote for 'testing' the inputFile.